# Easy way to use Secure module (or similar) on all controllers in Play?

Tags: controller, playframework

I'd like to know if there's a way I can tell Play to use the Secure module for every controller, without having to add `With(Secure.class)` to all my controllers or making all my controllers extend a single class. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can intercept every-request with a play-plugin. Just have a look on modules/docviewer. It's very easy to implement. At the moment I'm working on a security-module where everything is forbidden as a default.